# What character set should I assume the encoded characters in a URL to be in?

Tags: url

[RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) specifies the syntax for URL's, and mentions that

> URLs are written only with the graphic
>   printable characters of the
>   US-ASCII coded character set. The
>   octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not
>   used in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F
>   and 7F hexadecimal represent
>   control characters; these must be
>   encoded.

It does not, however, say what code set these octets then represent.

[RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) seems to try and improve on the situation, but:

> For original character sequences that
>   contain non-ASCII characters, however, the situation is more
>   difficult. Internet protocols that transmit octet sequences intended to
>   represent character sequences are expected to provide some way of
>   identifying the charset used, if there might be more than one
>   [RFC2277].  However, there is currently no provision within the
>   generic URI syntax to accomplish this identification. An individual URI
>   scheme may require a single charset, define a default charset, or
>   provide a way to indicate the charset used.
>
> It is expected that a systematic treatment of character encoding within URI will be
>   developed as a future modification of this specification.

Is there any unambigous way in which a client can determine in which character set to interpret encoded octets, or in which a server can determine what a client used to encode with ?

It looks to me like most servers default to UTF-8, but this seems to be a de facto choice more than a specified one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per your quote, URLs are ASCII. That's all.

URIs OTOH, allow for bigger charsets; usually UTF-8 as you said yourself.

The point to remember is that URLs are a subset of URIs. Therefore, the real question is, which of these is what you write in a browser?

I'd guess you can write an URI, and the browser should try its best to transform to an URL (which is what HTTP/1.1 support, AFAICR). For non-ASCII characters, that means hexcodes, usually coding UTF-8.

Comment: URLs are opaque identifiers that have no character encoding, the opaque identifier can be considered a binary string of characters that only has a meaning to the target host they are intended.  The target host can if it so wishes apply a character-set interpretation of the URL data.  This means the client has no control over the meaning or character set and no way to express a choice since the interpretation of the URL is 100% a matter for the server.  So to answer the original question you can not assume any character-set it is server implementation specific so ask the server administrator.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the specification you are looking for is [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987), which describes IRIs - Internationalized Resource Identifiers.